# YouTube API playlist thumnail image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube

I'm using this [YouTube API](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/playlists?orderby=updated&v=2&alt=jsonc&start-index=1&max-results=11) for playlist data   and there doesn't seem to be a thumbnail image of the playlist as it is on YouTube.

Anybody have any ideas or come across this problem before?

Comment: What is the response you get from youtube?

Comment: What is your request? Please edit your post with the information as others will be able to read it and understand your question better.

Comment: m getting playlist id from YouTUbe API hit...like id":"73186A83D4A51B3C","created":"2011-04-19T15:54:56.000Z","updated":"2011-04-29T13:21:47.000Z","author":"TheSpeedFix","title":"AeroCarCare","description":"","size":2

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your JSON feed: '&prettyprint=true', then see what kind of response you get.
The problem might be solved by removing 'alt=jsonc'. Have a look here:
[Youtube JSON-C](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc.html)